# Visual Studio Extension Development: How reference pending changes window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

i need to develop a Visual Studio Extension, but even if looked around i didn't find a sample on how reference VS tool window (in my case pending changes) to customize it and add some extra features.

Could someone maybe give a an hint or url where i can look for this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you pending changes is a Team Explorer Tool Window, If you want to add  custom button to Team Explorer, please refer to:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/198f36bf-0606-4b99-b736-1a786cdf5183/how-to-add-a-custom-button-in-teamexplorer-queryresultgrid-toolbar-and-workitem-toolbar?forum=vsx

If you want to add other features, I would suggest that you can create a [custom tool window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn951126.aspx), add the feathers as you want, Get the Pending Changes information via [IPendingChangesExt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.controls.extensibility.ipendingchangesext(v=vs.120).aspx) , and here is a sample about [HOWTO: Get the Pending Changes in the Team Explorer of Visual Studio from a package](https://www.mztools.com/articles/2015/MZ2015007.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly what I need